# how to create multiple screen sizes?

Tags: android, android-layout

I tried many times but not successful. anybody can tell me step by step with some xml help that how to work with multiple screen size in android?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello. This is the developer guide : https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Comment: You need to put some code in the question so that one can point out what wrong you are doing

Answer (score 1):

Follow this:
After you created layout in your first size (Suppose that your code is as follow):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

</RelativeLayout>
```

When you move cursor and click on `<RelativeLayout` tag, a hint is appeared at the start of line:
[image]

When click on hint, it help you to create layout in other configuration using current layout:
[image]

Now, you can use of Size item (without renaming anythings):
[image]

In new window you can select your new size and then press OK button:
[image]

Now see directories. Your layout nested in to a folder that contains layout with different sizes. You can change new layout as you want.
[image]

Note that if you want use of same activity, it's necessary to use same naming in other configurations.